# iOS: Finding out who is first responder on a dynamically changed UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, resignfirstresponder

I have a `UITableView` which have custom cells with `UITextField`s in them. My `UITableView` is defined on my `MainViewController`, while my cells are defined in the `CustomCell`class. Each time I press a button, a new cell is created. I am having trouble making my cell's `UITextField` resign first responder, since cells are dynamically added and defined in a different class than the main controller. How do I do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell the UITableView to `endEditing:`.

Comment: wow, ty very much, I thought I had to tell the specific `UITextField` from the specific `UITableViewCell` to end editing. You, sir, made my night.

Comment: It came from my book! Last sentence of 4th paragraph of this section: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_summoning_and_dismissing_the_keyboard

Comment: Is it possible to have your book sent to Brazil?

Comment: It's a URL; all you have to do is click it. Amazing, the technology they've got these days.

Comment: "This is a full free preview of my book, Programming iOS 6, by Matt Neuburg. Please report errors to me. If this free preview has helped you, please consider rewarding my time and effort by buying the actual book! You can find it in published form at http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029717.do. Copyright 2013 Matt Neuburg."I was actually thinking of buying it if the print version could be sent to Brazil...